# How to replace system ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have some version of ruby in rvm, I want to replace my system ruby(2.0) to 1.9.

I try to use `` `$ rvm --default use 1.9 ``, But It only effect to terminal. Not effect to sublime

Answer (score 1):

Example from my machine, first I list the rubies known to rvm

```
  $ rvm list

  rvm rubies

     jruby-1.7.4 [ x86_64 ]
     jruby-1.7.9 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
  =* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

  # => - current
  # =* - current && default
  #  * - default
```

Then I select the version of ruby I want to use

```
  $ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448 --default
  Using /Users/bjhaid/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

When I list the rubies again 1.9.3 is default
      $ rvm list

```
  rvm rubies

     jruby-1.7.4 [ x86_64 ]
     jruby-1.7.9 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
  =* ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
     ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

  # => - current
  # =* - current && default
  #  * - default

  $
```

Answer (score 1):

since you mention sublime and your path looks like OSX perhaps this will help.

http://upstre.am/blog/2011/07/sublime-text-2-with-rvm-on-osx/

Answer (score -1):

Probably you will need to uninstall your current system ruby (the one you have installed with system package manager), and downgrade it to 1.9.  System ruby is "outside of rvm"

updated:

Probably i need to explain a litle bit:
I have ubuntu system, and there is no "system" ruby installed, only ruby that comes with rvm:

```
shell:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

 # => - current
 # =* - current && default
 #  * - default

shell:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

shell:~$  rvm use system 
Now using system ruby.
shell:~$  ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
  * ruby1.8
  * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

so once again "system" ruby is the one that comes with system package manager.